# Deploying Zend Application gives error Autoloader class must implement Zend\Loader\SplAutoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos

Zend Application was developed on wamp server (windows). it works fine on windows machine. Deploying site on linux gives following errors.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Loader\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Autoloader class Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader must implement Zend\Loader\SplAutoloader' in /var/www/html/abc/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php
```

I have checked the version of php running on linux server i.e. 5.3.3 and ZF version by using

```
zf show version 
1.12.13
```

question on stack overflow is similar to my question
[[Zend framework 2 Skeleton App FATAL error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484399/zend-framework-2-skeleton-app-fatal-error][1])
but the answer clearly indicate that 5.3 version of php supports zf version. It is not helping me.

Comment: That's a ZF2 error. Don't trust the command line. What version of ZF did you develop your app with?

Comment: But which verison? 5.3.3 is too old to run the current version of ZF2. My guess is your server has a later version of ZF2 than you developed your site again. You either need to update PHP or install an older version of ZF2. since PHP 5.3 is past end of life, I'd suggest the former.

Comment: Thanks Tim Fountain... I was working on the problem, Just saw your answer.... You are right... Php 5.5 resolve the issue....